# Best way to handle images and links from a rest api and displaying them in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, I am pulling data from an API source and then displaying that data in the view, unlike Angular where you can use `src={{image.path}}` in the src, it does not work in React, therefore what would be the best way to get images and href urls to function and display properly?

My code so far is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../about/about.css';

class About extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="about">
                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div>
                        {this.state.data.map((post, indx) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="container about text-left mt-5" key={indx}>
                                    <h5>{post.title}</h5>
                                    <p>{post.description}</p>

                                    <div className="media">
                                        <img className="align-self-start mr-3" src="{post.urlToImage}" alt="Alt text"></img>
                                        <div className="media-body">
                                            <h5 className="mt-0">Top-aligned media</h5>
                                            <a href="{{post.url}}" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default About;
```

`src="{post.urlToImage}"` does not work and `<a href="{{post.url}}" target="_blank">Read More</a>` does not work either?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `""` to pass in a string, just use `{}` to pass in the property you're looking for.

```
src={post.urlToImage}
href={post.url}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using something in quotes which means String output: `src="{post.url}"`, just remove the quotes to pass the dynamic value as props like `src={post.url}`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../about/about.css';

class About extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="about">
                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div>
                        {this.state.data.map((post, indx) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="container about text-left mt-5" key={indx}>
                                    <h5>{post.title}</h5>
                                    <p>{post.description}</p>

                                    <div className="media">
                                        <img className="align-self-start mr-3" src={post.urlToImage} alt="Alt text"></img>
                                        <div className="media-body">
                                            <h5 className="mt-0">Top-aligned media</h5>
                                            <a href={post.url} target="_blank">Read More</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default About;
```

Happy codin'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Larz posted a few mins before, I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @sole Thanks, let us know if you need more. If you upvote, so you'd get upvoted!